# Q: rails-tutorial Preview page not working

Tags: railstutorial.org

I get this screen after following the rails tutorial instructions to show the Hello, world text in a browser window (Figure 1.15 in the book).

I seem to recall having to specify both the PORT and IP environment variables the last time I ran through the tutorial...but now can't find any reference to these in the book text.

[Preview Fails error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu5kd.png)

Comment: Do you have rails in the gemfile?

Comment: yes, the line that contains "rails" looks like this...                                      
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails',      '5.1.4'  good grief...so the "return" key doesn't work in these comments?  well, live and learn...I guess

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and I fixed it by running like this:

```
$ rails server -p $PORT -b $IP
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.4 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.4.0-p0), codename: Private Caller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:8080
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

I haven't yet figured out why I am getting the error, though.